# .htaccess rewrite - filename.html a /?c=filename

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, enlace

ESPAÑOL:
Hola, necesito que funcione con todos los enlaces html (menos con index), probé usar .htaccess pero no tuve suerte.

Por ejemplo...
que cambie este link de:
http://www.website.com/signup.html  a  http://www.website.com/?c=signup

También si entro directamente a http://www.website.com/?c=signup, debe ser un espejo de http://www.website.com/signup.html

¡Muchas gracias!

---

ENGLISH:
Hi, I need it to work with all html URLs (except index), I tried using .htaccess with no luck.

For example...
change this link from:
http://www.website.com/signup.html  to  http://www.website.com/?c=signup

Also if I enter directly to http://www.website.com/?c=signup, it must mirror http://www.website.com/signup.html

Thanks a lot!

**EDITADO** Logré hacerlo con este código: 
**EDIT** I managed to do it with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect from signup.html to /?c=signup
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html$ ?c=$1 [R,L]

# Rewrite from /?c=signup to signup.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ %1.html [QSD,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza expresiones regulares. Definimos un *atom*, y luego lo utilizamos por su índice. `$1`

Por ejemplo, esta regla haría lo que entiendo que pides.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+).html$ ? c=$1 [L]
```